# Why is the last element in associative array (index by table) not printed by?

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql, associative-array

This seems like a basic thing but i am not able to figure out. 
I have a PLSQL code block like below. It creates a simple sparse associative array and stores 5 elements at subscripts as -1,0,1,2,100.

Printing ARRAY.LAST gives 100 and ARRAY.COUNT gives 5. In my while loop it prints all elements properly. 
But For loop going from ARRAY.FIRST to ARRAY.LAST prints only the elements at consecutive subscripts till 2, even though ARRAY.LAST gives 100

```
DECLARE
    TYPE assoc_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    table1 assoc_array;
    i BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    table1(-1) := 100;
    table1(0) := 101;
    table1(1) := 102;
    table1(2) := 103;
    table1(100) := 104;

    i := table1.FIRST;

    dbms_output.put_line(table1.FIRST);
    dbms_output.put_line(table1.LAST);
    dbms_output.put_line(table1.COUNT);

    i := table1.first;

    while (i is not null)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line( table1(i) );
        i := table1.next(i);
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line( '***');

    for i IN table1.FIRST .. table1.LAST
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(table1(i) );
    end loop;
END;
```

Output looks like:

```
-1
100
5
100
101
102
103
104
***
100
101
102
103
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this snippet to your block to see the reason, which is ORA-01403:

```sql
  ...
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
```

Your loop doesn't loop through the effective array indexes. It loops from `-1 .. 100`, and when you try to acces `table1(3)`, well, you cannot.

Alternatively, you could run this:

```sql
FOR i IN table1.FIRST .. table1.LAST LOOP
  IF table1.EXISTS(i) THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line(table1(i));
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

But that's not a good idea, because it's quite inefficient to loop through all integer values that you already know are not indexes of your associative array.

Answer (score 1):

`ARRAY.FIRST` is the smallest index number in your array, so in your case it will be the -1. On the other hand `ARRAY.LAST` took the greatest index number (100).

Then the `FOR` loop from the smallest index to the greatest with the step of 1. But when it reachs a non existing index it will throw an exception.

So just add one `IF` statement inside your loop to check that the element at a particular index exists.

```
IF array.EXISTS(i) THEN
  -- do something
 null;
END IF;
```